# C code compiles fine on linux but won't work in Visual studio

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio

I have a simple c program (It's a base program without any GUI) , 
on linux this code compiles and runs without any issue with gcc compiler, now I have to compile the same code on windows with Visual Studio 2013, with both visual c and intel compilers, I have selected new console application program following this [guide](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/tali/E15/Visual_C.html)

but get tons of these error messages

```
error : declaration may not appear after executable statement in block  myfile.c
```

at all the line with variables declarations, (also on a simple `int i;` )

the only libraries that I use are these

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <xmmintrin.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you show some code snippet ?

Comment: Visual Studio's C compiler does not deserve to be called a C compiler.

Comment: @Mysticial Neither does its C++ compiler ;) *har har har*

Comment: @Borgleader: No, its C++ compiler doesn't deserve to be called a C compiler, yet it compiles C a lot better than the C compiler does.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That is, the common subset of C and C++ is greater than the common subset of C and MS-C! Funny.

Comment: @rodrigo: There's no such thing as "MS-C".  It's a C89 compiler.  And yes, C++11 is closer to being a superset of C11 than C89 is.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Actually, with MS-C I meant C89 plus MS extensions (minus anything that may be missing, not sure if there is anything).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that your program has *[Mixed Declarations and Code](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.2/gcc_5.html#SEC92)*. VS doesn't support mixed type declaration (or you can say it doesn't support C99 completely).
In mixed declarations and code, for example, you could do:

```
int i;
...
i++;
int j = i + 2;
```

Each identifier is visible from where it is declared until the end of the enclosing block.

You need to move all the declaration to the beginning just like in C89. And you should note that *VS is not a C compiler*.

Comment: Or rename the file with `.cpp`, and put `extern "C" { }` around the whole thing.

Comment: @BenVoigt; Yes. This would be the best!

Comment: I don't use c99 flag so by default gcc should not use c99 syntax.

Comment: @andreaF; GCC uses this feature as an extension. I added the link.

Comment: @AndreaF: If you want to use GCC to check your code, compile with `-ansi -pedantic -std=c89`.  I bet you're using more C99 than you think.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with code such as this:

```
void foo()
{
    bar(); /* statement */

    int i; /* variable declaration */
}
```

That is not C90 valid, because there declarations must be at the beginning of the block, just after the opening brace (`{`).

In C99 and later it is correct, however, so GCC accepts it, (C90 is 15 years old).

Unfortunately MS-VC does not, and will not, support C99, so your code will not compile there.

You can fix it manually, by moving the declaration to the top of the block (1), add a lot of braces (2), try to compile it as C++, of change the compiler... that's up to you!

Example 1:

```
void foo()
{
    int i;

    bar();
    /* beware! if i was initialized, add the initialization here, not there */
}
```

Example 2 (hidden braces):

```
void foo()
{
    bar();

    {int i;
}} /*all the closing braces should be at the end of the function */
```

Comment: Thanks +1 (unfortunately I can accept only 1 answer)